# Un-concatenating a signal

Tags: verilog

I am using {} to concatenate several signals into a bus, is there a easy way to reverse it?

```
assign bus = {signal1, signal2, signal3};
```

I am trying to accomplish something similar to

```
assign {signal1, signal2, signal3} = bus;
```

currently, I am doing

```
assign signal1 = bus[0];
assign signal2 = bus[1];
assign signal3 = bus[2];
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you solve your problem.

Comment: haha I was just pulling stuff out of my ass, who knew it would work!

Comment: Complete working code here: [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/34)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are asking how to assign the bits of a bus to various signal names.

So if your signal is lets say 40 bits for example:

```
 wire [39:0] bus;
```

Then we can, for example, assign the 20 MSBs to one other signal name (alias), and the 20 LSBs to a different signal name.

```
wire [19:0] signal1, signal2;

assign {signal1,signal2} = bus;
```

What we have done here is to say, "Take all the bits of bus and signal2 is assigned to the 20 LSBs, and signal1 is equal to the other MSBs (which happen to be 20 bits).